# To pass argument to one powershell script from another powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a two powershell scripts a.ps1 & b.ps1. Im calling b.ps1 script inside the a.ps1 script.
I need to pass two variables as an arguments from a.ps1 to b.ps1 like below.

```
//a.ps1 Script starts here
 $variable1 ="This is Variable1"
 $variable2 ="This is Variable2"
```

Note: Im calling b.ps1 script inside this a.ps1 script like below and passing the above variables as an arguments to b.ps1

```
. C:\filepath\b.ps1 $variable1 $variable2 //Calling b.ps1 script

//b.ps1 contains below code
$getVariable1= $args[0]
$getVariable2= $args[1]
echo $getVariable1
```

But the above echo command from b.ps1 prints nothing. What is wrong with above arguments passing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's with the extra space in the b.ps1 call?

Once I corrected that, I get the expect results. Also, you never need Write-* (echo) if all you are doing is sending to the screen. Output to the screen is the default.

Lastly, no need for the // for comments here, the # and <##> works just fine on this site, as shown below.

Environment

```
$PSVersionTable

<#
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.503
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.17763.503}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.503
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
#>

Get-ExecutionPolicy
RemoteSigned
```

Content

```
# a.ps1
'running a.ps1 script, calling b.ps1'
$variable1 = "This is Variable1"
$variable2 = "This is Variable2"

.\b.ps1 $variable1 $variable2
```

Content

```
# b.ps1
'running b script'
'Showing output from a.ps1 variables'
$getVariable1= $args[0]
$getVariable2= $args[1]

$getVariable1
```

Results

```
 .\a.ps1
running a.ps1 script, calling b.ps1
running b script
Showing output from a.ps1 variables
This is Variable1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible issues:

- The line comment prefix is `#` (instead of `//`)
- The execution policies ( especially their defaults ) might prevent your script `b.ps1` to be called. Details is [this MS article](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-6) ( you would be hinted at this article by powershell after attempting to run `a.ps` from the command line, though ).
  The linked article also details how to set the policies properly ( in a nutshell for execution from the command line: `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process`

Comment: I have used // to give comments just for you guys understanding here. Thanks will check the article you provided.